# Select2 textbox width misbehaving

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, jquery-select2

I am having alot of trouble with select2 dropdown lists.

Im working in wordpress and my problem is that the select box does not fill its width. The wierd thing is that the dropdown arrow is at the correct position but the width of the select "textbox" is only as big as the currently selected content text.

[See how the textbox is only as big as it´s content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmlaK.png)

[different content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXDqz.png)

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<li>
            <label for="flokkur" >Flokkur <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <select name="flokkur" id="flokkur" class="sj_select2" style="width: 100%">
                    <option > Vörukaup m.Vsk</option>
                    <option > Rekstrarvörur og annar framl. kosntn. m.Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Rekstrar kostnaður húsnæðis m.Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Húsaleiga m. Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Húsaleiga án Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Gjalfærð smááhöld og búnaður m. Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Viðhald áhalda og tækja m. Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Ýmis akeypt þjónusta m. Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Ýmis skrifstofu kostnaður m. Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Lausafjár tækjaleiga m. Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Sölukostnaður auglýsingar og fl. m. Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Ýmis kostnaður með 11% Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Ýmis annar kostnaður (funda og Vsk.) án Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Risna og gjafir án Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Ferðakostnaður án Vsk. annar en rekstur bifreiðar </option>
                    <option> Rekstur bifreiðar Ökutæki án Vsk. </option>
                </select>

</li>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".sj_select2").select2({
    width: '100%'
  });
    jQuery("#test_select").select2();
});
</script>
```

I have tried all sorts of solutions such as

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery(".sj_select2").select2({ width: 'resolve' });           
});
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery(".sj_select2").select2({ width: 'auto' });           
});
```

I have also messed alot with css to try to figue this out but so far no luck.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Below answer is working well for you or not?

Comment: Unfortunetly not, but i found a solution. Removing the <li> tags around the select element solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above solution did not resolve this issue in my case.

The solution that worked for me in the end was simply removing the list "li" tags that enclosed the select element.

Answer (score 0):

I think some issues in select2 js or css file.Please try this code.Here i have included the latest css and js (**4.0.3**)

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".sj_select2").select2({
    width: '100%'
  });
    jQuery("#test_select,#test1").select2();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <li>
            <label for="flokkur" >Flokkur <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <select name="flokkur" id="flokkur" class="sj_select2" style="width: 100%">
                    <option > Vörukaup m.Vsk</option>
                    <option > Rekstrarvörur og annar framl. kosntn. m.Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Rekstrar kostnaður húsnæðis m.Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Húsaleiga m. Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Húsaleiga án Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Gjalfærð smááhöld og búnaður m. Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Viðhald áhalda og tækja m. Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Ýmis akeypt þjónusta m. Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Ýmis skrifstofu kostnaður m. Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Lausafjár tækjaleiga m. Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Sölukostnaður auglýsingar og fl. m. Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Ýmis kostnaður með 11% Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Ýmis annar kostnaður (funda og Vsk.) án Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Risna og gjafir án Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Ferðakostnaður án Vsk. annar en rekstur bifreiðar </option>
                    <option> Rekstur bifreiðar Ökutæki án Vsk. </option>
                </select>

</li>
<div style="margin-top:10px"></div>
<select name="test1" id="test1" class="sj_select2">
                    <option > Vörukaup m.Vsk</option>
                    <option > Rekstrarvörur og annar framl. kosntn. m.Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Rekstrar kostnaður húsnæðis m.Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Húsaleiga m. Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Húsaleiga án Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Gjalfærð smááhöld og búnaður m. Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Viðhald áhalda og tækja m. Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Ýmis akeypt þjónusta m. Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Ýmis skrifstofu kostnaður m. Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Lausafjár tækjaleiga m. Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Sölukostnaður auglýsingar og fl. m. Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Ýmis kostnaður með 11% Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Ýmis annar kostnaður (funda og Vsk.) án Vsk. </option>
                    <option> Risna og gjafir án Vsk.</option>
                    <option> Ferðakostnaður án Vsk. annar en rekstur bifreiðar </option>
                    <option> Rekstur bifreiðar Ökutæki án Vsk. </option>
                </select>
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help and prompt response. Unfortunetly this did not fix the issue, but by chance i found a solution while applying yours. If I simply removed the <li> and </li> tags from around the select2 box then the problem dissappeared.